# How do you count unique lists (including combinations) within a list?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, python-itertools

How do I build a set of lists that are unique but cover the  of the potential values within that list.  Example below.

Using the example CSV data:

```
1,2,3,4
2,3,4,2
1,4,2,3
1,2,4,3
1,5,4,2
```

I do not care about the first item (field) in each row; the next 3 fields do I do care about, e.g., `2,3,4`, `3,4,2`, `4,2,3`, etc....

In this case the count would be 4 for the set `{2,3,4}`, and 1 for the last set, `{2,4,5}`.

What is a good way to accomplish this?

I tried using itertools Count but it seems that doesn’t take into consideration the items can be out of order. Is there a flag I can use to specify they type of matching it performs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to sort the fields for each row before adding them to your counter.

Since you asked about CSV, I'll show a complete solution for dealing with the input from a CSV file, but @Yolao_21's answer is great for just dealing with a list of a list of numbers.

I went for sorting fields 2-4, then converting that sorted list to a tuple (so it could be hashed and added to the counter, which I'll call a "TupleSet"):

```py
import csv
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()

with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        t = tuple(sorted(row[1:4]))  # TupleSet of fields 2-4
        c[t] += 1


print(c)
```

```py
Counter({('2', '3', '4'): 4, ('2', '4', '5'): 1})
```

If you want to keep track of which row lead to a particular set (I'm just making up requirements here, for fun), you could also create a dict of TupleSets to a list of rows.  Something like:

```py
{
    ('2','3','4'): [
                     ['1','2','3','4'], 
                     ['2','3','4','2'], 
                     ...
                   ],
    ('2','4','5'): [
                     ['1','5','4','2']
                   ]
}
```

The following also adds in the row's original 1-based index:

```py
import csv
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    all_rows = list(reader)


c = Counter()
tset_row_map = defaultdict(list)

for i, row in enumerate(all_rows, start=1):
    t = tuple(sorted(row[1:4]))
    c[t] += 1

    tset_row_map[t].append((i, row))


# Sort by highest-count first
sorted_items = sorted(c.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

for tset, count in sorted_items:
    print(f"Set {tset} had a count of {count}:")
    for i, row in tset_row_map[tset]:
        print(f"  row {i}: {row}")
```

I expanded the input CSV to:

```
1,5,4,2
1,2,3,4
2,3,4,2
1,4,2,3
1,2,4,3
9,8,7,6
4,7,8,6
```

and that prints:

```
Set ('2', '3', '4') had a count of 4:
  row 2: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
  row 3: ['2', '3', '4', '2']
  row 4: ['1', '4', '2', '3']
  row 5: ['1', '2', '4', '3']
Set ('6', '7', '8') had a count of 2:
  row 6: ['9', '8', '7', '6']
  row 7: ['4', '7', '8', '6']
Set ('2', '4', '5') had a count of 1:
  row 1: ['1', '5', '4', '2']
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your requirements, I think the most simple & elegant data structure for your use-case is a `dict` where the keys are `frozenset`s of your combos, and the corresponding value to each key is the count of how often they occur:

```
from __future__ import print_function

DATA = (
    '1,2,3,4',
    '2,3,4,2',
    '1,4,2,3',
    '1,2,4,3',
    '1,5,4,2',
)
results = {}

for data in DATA:
    key = frozenset(data.split(',')[1:])
    results[key] = results.setdefault(key, 0) + 1

print(results)
```

In the snippet above, I have a constant for your sample data -- you can read the data in however/from wherever you want, i.e., files, database, spreadsheet, `curl`/`wget`, intranet/LAN, etc. That's followed by an empty `dict` for the results. As the code loops through the data, the 1st element is dropped since you "don't care" about it. The rest are thrown into a `frozenset`. Python sets are great (deduping and) desorting structures (why sort when you don't have to?), because `{2,3,4}` == `{3,4,2}`, and so on.

Dictionary keys must be immutable, hence why I use a `frozenset` instead of a normal `set` (plus I'm not growing/shrinking those sets either), then I either initialize the count to `0` if I've never seen this combo before or increment it otherwise. Finally, the results are displayed.

I have a "bad" habit of making my code work on both Python 2 & 3, so it's amusing to see they "order" the set elements differently even though the answers are both the same and correct:

```
$ python3 75595319.py
{frozenset({'4', '2', '3'}): 4, frozenset({'4', '2', '5'}): 1}
$ python2 75595319.py
{frozenset(['3', '2', '4']): 4, frozenset(['2', '5', '4']): 1}
```

Yes, I *could've* used utilities from `csv` and `collections` but didn't want the overhead as this was doable in pure Python in a fairly straightforward way while also minimizing the total number of function/method calls and unnecessary computation (like sorting). Furthermore, both sets & dictionaries are hashed data structures, meaning O(1) on average. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to combine sorting and Counter and string:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],  [2,3,4,2],  [1,4,2,3], [1,2,4,3], [1,5,4,2]]

>>> Counter(map(lambda x: str(sorted(x[1:])), a))
Counter({'[2, 3, 4]': 4, '[2, 4, 5]': 1})
```